# Using HTML in android

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to get the value of a variable that I use in my Java class to a html page using a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)? For example I will get the total amount and transfer into an online payment.

Does anybody know how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView's addJavascriptInterface method to do this.

Comment: do you have any link of tutorial to do that?

Comment: The official docs http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

have a good example of going in the opposite direction, but it should be relatively easy to adapt it.